# MATLAB: How to return value -1 for non-scalars

Tags: matlab

Write a function called day_diff that takes four scalar positive integer inputs, month1, day1, month2, day2. These represents the birthdays of two children who were born in 2015. The function returns a positive integer scalar that is equal to the difference between the ages of the two children in days. Make sure to check that the input values are of the correct types and they represent valid dates. If they are erroneous, return -1. An example call to the function would be:

```
dd = day_diff(1,30,2,1);
```

which would make dd equals 2. You are not allowed to use the built-in function `datenum` or `datetime`.

```
function dd = day_diff(month1, day1, month2, day2)

if (month1 && month2 > 0) || (month1 && month2 <= 12)

    if month1 == 1 && month2 == 1
        if day1 == day2
            total1 = day1;
            total2 = day2;
        elseif day1 ~= day2
            total1 = max(day1,day2);
            total2 = min(day1,day2);
        end
    elseif month1 == 1 && month2 == 2
        total1 = day1;
        total2 = day2 + 31;
    elseif (month1 == 2 && day1 <= 28) && month2 == 1
        total1 = day1 + 31;
        total2 = day2;
    elseif month1 == 1 && month2 == 12
        total1 = day1;
        total2 = day2 + 334;
    elseif month1 == 2 && month2 == 3
        total1 = day1 + 31;
        total2 = day2 + 59;
    elseif month1 == 7 && month2 == 9
        total1 = day1 + 181;
        total2 = day2 + 243;
    elseif month1 == 1 && month2 == 4
        total1 = day1;
        total2 = day2 + 90;
    else
        dd = -1;
        return
    end
end

if (day1<1 || day1>31) || (month1<1 || month1>12)
    dd = -1;
    return

elseif day2<1 || day2>31 || (month2<1 || month2>12)
    dd = -1;
    return

else
    dd = (max(total1,total2)) - (min(total1,total2));
end
```

My function performs well unless I have a vector as an input argument (like (12,3,[3,4],5). I tried using `~isscalar` but it doesn't seem to work the way I did it.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if *any* of the input is not an array you can do:

```
if any([length(month1)~=1, length(month2)~=1, length(day1)~=1, length(day2)~=1;])
   dd=-1;
   return;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
function dd = day_diff(varargin)

if nargin~= 4 || any(~cellfun(@isscalar,varargin))
  dd = -1; return;
end

month1 = varargin{1};
day1 = varargin{2};
month2 = varargin{3};
day2 = varargin{4};

... rest of your code
```

Answer (score -2):

Solution is not correct. For example if you will use (8, 29, 8 25) you must have 4 days but in your programm you will have -1. All programm was written with a lot of wrong